# Show latest posts on responsive theme

Tags: homepage, recent-posts, responsive

I've installed Responsive theme on [my new blog](http://matan.name/wordpress/). I want the home page to show my recent posts, so I configured `Settings->Reading` to show my 10 recent posts, instead of a static page.

Alas, the static home page (with the "Call to Action button") remained. Any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and you can find out more on our [support forum](http://themeid.com/forum/topic/537/reading-settings-changing-default-homepage/) as well.

Thanks for using Responsive,
Emil

Answer (score 0):

Create a page from the template `Blog excerpt (summary)`, and set it as the default page.

Comment: An explanation would make this a viable answer.